# Provided address undefined is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or it's an indirect IBAN address which can't be converted

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, dapps, nodejs, java

I'm building a Dapp and when i im click the mint button i get this error

> Error: Provided address undefined is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or it's an indirect IBAN address which can't be converted.

and this is how my code looks like

```
export const publicSale = async (mintAmount) => {
if(window.ethereum.selectedWallet) {
    return {
        success : false,
        status : 'To be able to mint, you need to connect your wallet'
    }
}

const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(window.ethereum.selectedWallet, 'latest');
const tx = {
    to : config.contractAddress,
    from : window.ethereum.selectedWallet,
    value : parseInt(web3.util.toWei(String(config.price * mintAmount), 'ether')).toString(16),
    gas : String(30000 * mintAmount),
    data : NFTContract.methods.publicSaleMint(mintAmount).encodeABI(),
    nonce : nonce.toString(16)
}

try {
    const txHash = await window.ethereum.request({
        method : 'eth_sendTransaction',
        params : [tx]
    });

    return {
        success : true,
        status : 'You have successfully minted your NFT'
    }
} catch (error) {
    return {
        success : false,
        status : 'Somthing went wrong ' + error.message
    }
}
```

}

this is where the error goes

> 102 | const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(window.ethereum.selectedWallet, 'latest');

Answer (score 0):

If this is all the code, it looks like you don't have a function to connect the users wallet. Also it should be: `window.ethereum.selectedAddress` not `window.ethereum.selectedWallet`

you have to use `window.ethereum.request` here is one way of doing this :

```
if(window.ethereum){
   try {
      const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
         method: "eth_requestAccounts",
      });
      console.log(accounts)           
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
   }
}
```